# Rails uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I'm getting this error from the view /tasks/index2:

```
uninitialized constant Taskstatu
```

But, my app doesn't even have `Taskstatu` in it.  It does have a taskstatuses table.

The view contains this line of code:

```
        <td><%= task.taskstatus.statuscode %></td>
```

I'm not sure what else to show you.  I can't understand where the constant `Taskstatu` comes from??

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a mismatching problem between your model and the underlying table. Rename your model to `TaskStatus` and your table to `:task_statuses`.

The reason:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > "TaskStatus".underscore.pluralize
 => "task_statuses"
2.0.0p247 :002 > "task_statuses".classify
 => "TaskStatus"
```